# I want to create a Visual Recipe site on WordPress, any suggestions or tips on how i can do it?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I would like to create a visual recipe site, which lists how to make a dish in step by step through pictures.. Is it possible to create a custom page template where i can the following fields.

1.Dishname(title) 2.Introduction(Brief info) 3.Ingredients 4.upload photo input.. followed by add more pic

Is it possible in wordpress, you have any effective ideas? please share :)

here is a screenshot of what i have in my mind https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsWKg.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes Wordpress can do this sort of things.

You could create a custom post type called "Recepies", and a custom taxonomy called "Ingredients". Everything else is already included in the default WP setup, "Dishname" would be your post title, "Introduction" can be the "Excerpt" field, and photos are handled by the media gallery.

Comment: but its going to be a community site, users can register and add contents.. so all the users wont know how to add posts and also use custom fields.. usability is screwed.. 
any solutions for that.. n

Comment: I am looking for something like this http://i.imgur.com/rsWKg.png

Comment: @nicolas, this could be implemented with a plugin like [Gravity forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) for example. It lets your users fill out forms that create posts once they are submitted.